# Wordpress orderby meta_value_num and order DESC issue

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to order my events with event date but i am facing an issue with order

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'         => 'post',
    'category_name'     => 'events',
    'post_status'       => 'publish', // just for me
    'meta_key'          => 'event_start',
    'orderby'           => 'meta_value_num',
    'order'             => 'DESC',
    'posts_per_page'    => 20,
    
);
```

thats how my query looks like. Problem is when events are in same date it loads A for B, C D its ok but when i refresh few times if A and B has same date it some times loads B first and sometimes A Could you please help me to find whats wrong with the query.

Comment: Can you give us some of the examples of the values in the `event_start` meta key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thing is that probably Wordpress applies default ordering to the events which have the same events_start value. Try adding more order conditions to it, for example, by alphabetic order or by publication date:

```
// Alphabetic
$args = array(
    'post_type'         => 'post',
    'category_name'     => 'events',
    'post_status'       => 'publish', // just for me
    'meta_key'          => 'event_start',
    'orderby'           => array(
        'meta_value_num' => 'DESC',
        'title' => 'ASC',
    ),
    'posts_per_page'    => 20,
);
// By publication date
$args = array(
    'post_type'         => 'post',
    'category_name'     => 'events',
    'post_status'       => 'publish', // just for me
    'meta_key'          => 'event_start',
    'orderby'           => array(
        'meta_value_num' => 'DESC',
        'date' => 'ASC',
    ),
    'posts_per_page'    => 20,
);
```